# Crashlytics Beta Can't Find Testers UDID

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, crashlytics

I've scoured the internet for the last few days trying to figure out why Crashlytics can't find my testers device.

[image]

In my developer account, I added the testers device in the devices tab, included that device in a provisioning profile, and then downloaded and double clicked the profile to install it on my computer.

[image]

It looks like the provisioning profile has been installed successfully in my ~Library/mobiledevice/provisioningprofiles folder. 
[image]

In Xcode I've tried deleting my developer account and adding it again. I've tried restarting xcode. I've tried deleting the profiles from my ~Library/mobiledevice/provisioningprofiles folder and reinstalling them.

I originally couldn't get it to install on my own phone either and I was getting the dreaded "The app could not be installed at this time" but I fixed that under build settings by selecting my "personal team" as the development team.

[image]

I also changed this in the general tab to match. I don't know why I have multiple "team" options to choose from in the first place or if this could be related to my problem.

[image]

I don't know what else to check or try or do, and I keep looking at the same things over and over again online so if anyone has some fresh insight for me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of distribution method are you looking into using? If Ad Hoc, do you have an Ad Hoc distribution profile, with the devices you want to test on, set up?

Edit: It seems to me you dont, you need both a development AND a distribution profile.

Comment: hmm, so I made the Ad Hoc certificate and profile. I installed and restarted xcode but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I had to uncheck "automatically manage signing" and import my new profiles. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Great ! U saved my day..I was desparately looking for a fix for this